# iPhone: localization / internationalization default strings file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, localization, internationalization

I currently have two supported languages: English and Spanish. Thus I have two `main.strings` files for each language. One in `en.lproj` and one in `es.lproj`.

What I want now is that the English `main.strings` is the default file if a user with a locale other than `en` or `es` arrives at the application, e.g. `de` or `fr`.

I know I can set it manually for each string in the code with the `defaultString` parameter:

```
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key, @"main",[NSBundle mainBundle], defaultString, comment);
```

But I would prefer to not enter it there again (and have to change it at two places), but rather have the `en` `main.strings` file as a default for any other "unsupported" locale.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What I want now is that the English
>   main.strings is the default file if a
>   user with a locale other than en or es
>   arrives at the application, e.g. de or
>   fr.

Did you try that? I’m almost certain the application will fall back to the English locale without you doing anything at all. Even the system dialogs will come up in English unless your application explicitly supports the current locale.

Comment: Argh. You're totally right. Stupid of me for not testing thoroughly. Instead of using a completely different language I used "es" for testing, for which I already had an empty string file created.

Comment: the fallback depends of the sequence of [NSLocale preferredLanguages] rather than default english .  for example if you switch from chinese to deutsch ,  the first one is deutsch and the second one is chinese , so if the app support chinese , so it displays chinese instead of english

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid this long syntax, I have another solution posted here

[Localizing strings in iOS: default (fallback) language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263859/localizing-strings-in-ios-default-fallback-language/8784451#8784451)