# how to set iOS default localizable string for a key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, localizable.strings

I have create a `Localizable.strings` file with 2 language, en & jp.

en: `"key"="english";`

jp: `"key"="日本";`

It works good when using en & jp.

```
_title.text = NSLocalizedString(@"key",nil);
```

But when I using other language,like German,the label will display `key` in the view.I want to show the key of `en` strings value default.

How to set to load `en` when the user using other language without en & jp?

Comment: Possibly duplicate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263859/localizing-strings-in-ios-default-fallback-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a `Localizable.strings` for "de", and then you can copy/paste from the "en" (if "en" was your main language you don't need to copy/paste, it will be created with the "en" strings)
But it's strange, I have my apps for "en" and "es" and the default is "en". I didn't do anaything.

Comment: thank you,but where can I set the default strings file if I don't want to use 'English' for default?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think that is what the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key in your info.plist is for @yellow

Comment: As borrrden said, I think it's the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion key in info.plist