# iOS i18n default fallback language

Tags: ios, internationalization

My application only has i18n for pt-PT.

However, when the phone is set to English or any other language my application displays the i18n keys instead of the values in pt-PT.

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263859/localizing-strings-in-ios-default-fallback-language ?

Comment: That solution requires me to change all the `NSLocalizedStrings`, which is quite undoable at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Info pane for your target, check the "Localization native development region" (`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`). This is probably `en` (since that's the default). This is the ultimate fall-back region. You should probably set this to `pt`.