# Is there the official way to set fallback localized language in iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, localizable.strings

In iOS app development, I could't find the official way to set fallback localized language.
I want to use English when user language is not included in my app's localizations.
I tried way to use Base Internationalisation, however, all doesn't work for all language.
Now, replace base.lproj to en.lproj, only languages added into my app are work well, but other languages are doesn't work well. (English not used, instead Korean is used when select a Russian...)

Some sites say that, set fallback language with value of "Localisation native development region", However, it didn't work well.
Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: In OS X, that is user's choice, not developer's. If iOS ever gets it, I imagine it would be done the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but do you understand what I want to say? Sorry, it may be because of my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds pretty much like the problem I was having. Spent a lot of time looking for a solution until I finally came up with this approach (my issue link and text below).

[iOS Localizable.strings not being retrieved from BASE file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680874/ios-localizable-strings-not-being-retrieved-from-base-file/25927392#25927392)

---

Found a way to determine whether or not I have a localization file for the currently selected language, and if not, I can pull from the **Base** localization file.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"];
if (path == nil)
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Base" ofType:@"lproj"];
}

NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"TAB_TITLE_Camera", @"Localizable", [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path], @"");
```

Simple solution that does everything I need.

Works on both **iOS 6.1** and **iOS 7.1**.

---

If you don't have a localization file for the currently selected language, or you want to specify a particular language, just set the value for **pathForResource** and you should get the language you want.

Comment: Best answer about ios localization ever. Thanks