# Why do I get different Locale.current in different Apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, locale, nsdateformatter

I have two different Apps that I run from XCode on the *same device*.

In AppDelegate application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I print out the following debugging message:

```
print( Locale.current )
```

In one App it prints out  `sv_SE` (as I would expect), but on the other App it prints out `en_SE` !!

As a result, `dateFormatter.string` will produce english names instead of the Swedish names that I where expecting.

```
func dayOfWeek(date:Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current // locale is  en_SE not sv_SE   ???
    let dayname =  dateFormatter.string(from: date).capitalized
    return dayname   // returns SATURDAY not LÖRDAG    
}
```

**Question:** Why do I get different locales in different Apps when ran on the same device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Locale.current reporting wrong language on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136456/locale-current-reporting-wrong-language-on-device?rq=1)

The answer was that `Locale.current` is *not* the locale set on the device, but a "compromise" between that locale what the App supports. My first App did support swedish but my second did not. To get the locale on the device one should instead use `Locale.preferredLanguages.first`, as is done in the answer to [Locale.current reporting wrong language on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136456/locale-current-reporting-wrong-language-on-device?rq=1).

Comment: Note that this was a recent change, I think in iOS 11.