# Why does Xamarin.iOS app honor system locale with NSDateFormatter even if app is not localized?

Tags: xamarin.ios

If in Settings->General->Languge & Region I set Language to French and Region to Canada and my developer system is us-EN, Xamarin.iOS (C#) honors the system setting even if my app is not localized to French.

In my test setup below:

This C# code:

```
Console.WriteLine($"App Locale {NSLocale.CurrentLocale.Identifier}");
Console.WriteLine($"System Locale {NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0]}");

var formatter = new NSDateFormatter();
formatter.DateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.Full;
formatter.TimeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.Short;
var stringDate = formatter.ToString(NSDate.Now);
Console.WriteLine(stringDate);
```

Prints:

```
App Locale fr_CA <<<---
System Locale fr-CA
samedi 15 octobre 2022 à 22:52
```

I like this behavior. Even though my app is not localized, at least I get localized date and time. It even honors the 24 hour time switch.

The equivalent Swift code does not, which my understanding is expected (see [Locale.current reporting wrong language on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136456/locale-current-reporting-wrong-language-on-device)):

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .full
formatter.timeStyle = .short
let stringDate = formatter.string(from: NSDate.now)
NSLog(stringDate)
```

Prints:

```
App Locale en_CA <<<---
System Locale fr-CA
Saturday, October 15, 2022 at 10:55 PM
```

So Xamarin is using fr_CA for what I am calling App Locale while Swift is using "en_CA" -- English language + Canada region -- as expected due to lack of localization.

What is Xamarin doing to force the app locale to system locale?

Answer (score 0):

To determine your app's language, iOS considers the order of the user's language preference (in the Settings app ->General -> Language & Region). Of course, if your app doesn't support the language, the system won't change it either. You can check if French is supported in your Xamarin.iOS and Swift App (Setting -> Your App -> Language).