# Views not mirrored for RTL languages

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization, right-to-left

I’m trying to localize my SwiftUI app for RTL languages but having trouble getting the views to be mirrored (navigation presentation direction, link chevron direction, toolbar items location etc.) I created a really simple project with the code below and when I edit the scheme to use “Right-to-Left Pseudolanguage” for “App Language” the views do get mirrored. However, when I choose Hebrew or Arabic or even set the simulator or device's system language to an RTL language, it doesn’t mirror and shows the same way it does for LTR languages.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      List {
        ForEach(1..<10) { i in
          NavigationLink {
            Text("Hello world")
          } label: {
            Text("\(i)")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The first image is what I expect (when using “Right-to-Left Pseudolanguage”) and second image is how it's shown for Hebrew/Arabic which isn't mirrored

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach using a variable to modify the layoutDirection

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRTL = false  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<10) { i in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Hello world")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            isRTL = Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier == "he"  // <-- here
        }
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, isRTL ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight)  // <-- here
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this made me notice the Locale was set to "en" even though it should've been "he". I realized with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136456/locale-current-reporting-wrong-language-on-device) that I first needed to add the localization file before the view will be mirrored.

Answer (score 1):

you can try explicitly setting the layout direction for your views. Check [LayoutDirection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layoutdirection), A direction in which SwiftUI can lay out content.

you can update your code like this to achieve `right to left` layouts.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<10) { i in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Hello world")
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, isRTL() ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight)
    }
    
    func isRTL() -> Bool {
        let languageCode = Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier
        return ["he", "ar"].contains(languageCode)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layoutdirection